# Retrieve XML Elements with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm having a hard time getting XML values from an XML file using XPath. The XML file has the following schema:

```
<devicesInfo>
    <deviceInfo>
    <deviceId>device1</deviceId>
    <macAddress>00:21:85:C9:19:A4</macAddress>
    <deviceType>deviceType1</deviceType>
    <deviceClass>/Server/SSH/Linux/</deviceClass>
    <location>location1</location>
    <productionState>Decommissioned</productionState>
</deviceInfo>
<deviceInfo>
    <deviceId>device2</deviceId>
    <macAddress>00:21:85:C9:19:F5</macAddress>
    <deviceType>deviceType1</deviceType>
    <deviceClass>/Server/SSH/Linux/</deviceClass>
    <location>location1</location>
    <productionState>Decommissioned</productionState>
</deviceInfo>
</devicesInfo>
```

What I tried to do is first of all, creating an instance of a custom class that I have made, which contains the following method:

```
  public NodeList getNodesList(String xmlQuery) throws XPathExpressionException {
        NodeList nodes = null;
        try {
            nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(xmlQuery, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return nodes;

    }
```

This method is then called with the query:

```
 NodeList nodes = xmlHandler.getNodesList("/devicesInfo/deviceInfo");
```

So far so good, for this is returning a **NodeList** with length 2, which is basically all the **deviceInfo** elements in the file.
What I wish to do next is iterating over each **deviceInfo** in order to get the value of its children (deviceId,macAddress,deviceType,deviceClass,location,productionState).

I tried to do the following:
`NodeList list = nodes.item(0).getChildNodes();`

Then

```
 System.out.println("First element is "+list.item(0).getTextContent());
```

This has given me an empty string. Though when I try to do this:

```
System.out.println("First element is "+list.item(1).getTextContent());
```

which is basically displaying item with index "1" rather than item with index "0", this ends up printing "device1" which is the value of the first element.

So in order to get the values of all the elements, I'd use the indices 1,3,5,7,9,11. I know I'm doing something wrong. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What is the relationship between `list` and `children` and `nodes`?

Comment: That was a typo. Children is actually "list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The children of the `<deviceInfo>` element include a number of whitespace-only text nodes.  You need to filter those out so that you're only iterating over the children that are elements, or parse the XML in a mode where white-space only text nodes inside `<deviceInfo>` elements are [ignored](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#isIgnoringElementContentWhitespace%28%29).

Comment: Wow man thanks a ton! This has fixed my problem!
I have created a process that produces this XML file. Can I somehow still format the XML file in that process without having to worry about the problem that I described above?

Comment: @MouhammedSoueidane, I believe there are ways using XML schemas to specify in which elements whitespace is ignorable.  If you're not validating using those, then I think your best bet is to first remove ignorable whitespace, perhaps by crafting an xpath query to match all text nodes that contain no non-space characters.  I wouldn't make your XML harder to debug by requiring no whitespace nodes.

Comment: Now that I know what the problem is, this has helped me solve it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229310/how-to-ignore-whitespace-while-reading-a-file-to-produce-an-xml-dom

Thanks a lot man, you were a life saver.

Comment: @MouhammedSoueidane, you're welcome.  Good luck with your project.