# Error with parsing DOM obtained from OMIM RESTful Web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, bioinformatics

> I am a beginner to web services can any one with experience please
>   help me with the following:
>
> I am writing a client trying to get information from OMIM RESTful web
>   services. I am using a key OMIM provideds after registration. (
>   http://omim.org/help/api ) I am successful at getting connection to
>   client. Also with the GET method I am able to fetch the required data
>   into a DOM document. Further, I could successfuly write the entire DOM
>   into a file on the local disk. However, I am unable to work with the
>   DOM using the standard parsing functions available for DOM.
>
> For example: I am able to get the root node with NodeList
>   nl=doc.getDocumentElement()and print onto the console. But when I try
>   to print the first child of the root node it returns null instead of
>   expected child node.
>
> Sample XML form:  webservices -> DOM -> file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><omim version="1.0">
    <clinicalSynopsisList>
    <clinicalSynopsis>
    <mimNumber>100070</mimNumber>
    <prefix>%</prefix>
    </clinicalSynopsis>
    </clinicalSynopsisList>
    </omim>
```

Please find my code below:

```
String path="http://api.omim.org:8000/api/clinicalSynopsis?mimNumber="+"100070"+"&include=clinicalSynopsis&format=xml&apiKey="+"<< xxxxx private key xxxxxxxxxx >> ";

                  URL url = new URL(path);

                  HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

                  Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);

                  Source src= new DOMSource(doc);

                  File file = new File("d:/text.xml");

                  Result rs = new StreamResult(file);

                  TransformerFactory tmf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

                  Transformer trnsfrmr = tmf.newTransformer();

                  trnsfrmr.transform(src, rs);

                  System.out.println("XML file is created successfully");

                  System.out.println("The root element is :: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


                  NodeList nl=doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

                  System.out.println("child nodelist length::"+nl.getLength());


                  System.out.println("First child node name :: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild().getNodeName());

                  System.out.println("Last child node name :: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getLastChild().getNodeName());
```

> Output I got:- XML file is created successfully The root element is ::
>   omim child nodelist length::3 First child node name :: #text Last
>   child node name :: #text
>
> In the output got the root node is “omim” and it has 3 children. but
>   returns null when tried printing the first and last child name.
>   Similarly getParent (), getChild (), getSibling () methods are not
>   working for me.
>
> Any help will be highly appreciated.
>
> Thank you,

Comment: This one should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229310/how-to-ignore-whitespace-while-reading-a-file-to-produce-an-xml-dom

Comment: cross posted on biostar: http://www.biostars.org/post/show/44705/parsing-dom-document-from-omim-restful-web-services/

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment and then I figured I would rather explain it further in the answer. You should have asked why the `root` has there 3 child nodes. There's only one child `element` - `clinicalSynopsisList` so why 3? The first and the last child are the linebreaks (and maybe you have whitespaces in there too) before and after the `clinicalSynopsisList`. Your node content is interpreted as [MIXED](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) since you don't have a schema or DTD to tell the parses that `omni` can only contain elemtents. If you had, [you could tell your parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace%28boolean%29) to ignore the ignorable [whitespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space) like it was explained in [that other SO question I referred you to in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229310/how-to-ignore-whitespace-while-reading-a-file-to-produce-an-xml-dom).

It's been a while since I worked with DOM API directly but I don't believe you can ask it for a first child *element*. Instead you could use XPath (start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html), for example, or search SO or google for examples) to get to your first child element or just iterate over the child nodes with DOM API and consult with their [node type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeType%28%29) (you would be ignoring [text nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#TEXT_NODE))

And I would also recommend to take a look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and marshalling technologies like [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) so that you didn't have to work with the "raw" XML that you read off of the webservice endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

(coy of my answer on [biostar](http://www.biostars.org/post/show/44705/parsing-dom-document-from-omim-restful-web-services/#44715)) I cannot currently use the OMIM API , but the following java code should do the work. I think your problem is that you assume that the first child of an XML node is an ELEMENT, which is wrong, it seems to be a TEXT node containing a carriage return.

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Biostar44705
    {
    private static final String API_KEY="XXXXXXXX"; 
    private DocumentBuilder builder;
    private Transformer echoTransformer=null;

    private Biostar44705()throws Exception
        {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setCoalescing(true);
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        TransformerFactory trf=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        this.echoTransformer =trf.newTransformer();
        this.echoTransformer .setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        this.echoTransformer .setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        }
    void get(int omimId)throws Exception
        {
        String uri="http://api.omim.org:8000/api/clinicalSynopsis?mimNumber="+omimId+
                "&include=clinicalSynopsis&format=xml&apiKey="+
                URLEncoder.encode(API_KEY,"UTF-8");
        Document dom=builder.parse(uri);
        Element root=dom.getDocumentElement();
        if(root==null) return;
        for(Node n1=root.getFirstChild();n1!=null;n1=n1.getNextSibling())
            {
            if(n1.getNodeType()!=Node.ELEMENT_NODE) continue;
            echoTransformer.transform(new DOMSource(n1),new StreamResult(System.out));
            break;
            }
        }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    new Biostar44705().get(100070);
    }
}
```