# Android Document Builder. Skip '\n' '\t' and spaces while parse xml

Tags: java, android, xml

My code

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
        getResources().getIdentifier("state",
                "raw", getPackageName()));
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
f.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
docBuilder = f.newDocumentBuilder();

state = docBuilder.parse(ins);
ins.close();
```

The xml to understand what happens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<State xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <IsOff>false</IsOff>
</State>
```

And the result you can see as **\n; IsOff and \n**

[image]

Also, you can see that I've set

> f.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

This XML would come from anywhere, so it is unacceptable to have such parsing results. Also, whiteSpaces would be inside text data of the document. So mechanically removing all Spaces; \n \t \r is not the answer. 
It is task of the parser to skip extra spaces and other chars between tags, right?

Comment: Those two questions may help you : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229310/how-to-ignore-whitespace-while-reading-a-file-to-produce-an-xml-dom 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703635/strip-whitespace-and-newlines-from-xml-in-java

Comment: yes.. i am very upset.